# Replace the question marks in this visual puzzle

Tags: visual

Try replace the question marks.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand the question. Must the four symbols on the right be used to replace the question marks? If so, there are eight question marks but only four symbols on the right. Also, there are no pre-placed symbols to use as a guide to replace the marks

Comment: Yes, the four symbols is all you need to replace the question marks. In other words, you will have to use the symbols more than once. No, i did not want to place any symbols because i thought that this problem woudn't be a challenge if i did. But i will definitely place a symbol soon if noone is able to solve it.

Comment: don't you think that there are multiple ways to solve this puzzle if no symbols already are placed?

Comment: Could be, but I really don't think so. The key is to identify what the objects represents and then place them correctly, in the 4 *differently* placed, rectangles.

Comment: I really think this puzzle is too broad

Comment: I believe I've solved this puzzle as it is without the need to have any symbols placed already. If nobody else solves it in the meantime I'll write it up later when I have the chance. No need to go adding further clues IMHO - if I can solve it like this, I'm sure someone else can too :)

Comment: Yes it should be solvable :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The four symbols are:

> The letters N, E, S, W inside a square or circle.

Therefore the question marks should be replaced by

> the pair of letters indicating that compass direction, i.e.
>  NW NE
>  SW SE

Comment: @Prim3numbah This is precisely what I made it too (re my comment on the question above), although when I first saw it (and when it was giving other users grief!) I believe all the symbols were reflections of these characters, which made for two conceivably valid solutions... I think your last edit may have removed much of the challenge to your puzzle! (No offence to the estimable Jaap!)

Comment: @Stiv Yes you are right, they were reflections in the beginning which wouldve made it harder. But when people started to downvote etc, i guess i just wanted to make it easier :D

Comment: @Jaap Yes, this is indeed the correct answer :)